# How to return specific option type by splitting a string using scala?

Tags: string, scala

I have a following string and I want to split it using scala

```
"myInfo": "name-name;model-model;number-10"
```

I want to split value of myInfo string such that I can access myName and its value seperately. e.g. myName:name, model:R210 etc

I am using following code to split string.

```
val data = (mainString \ "myInfo").as[String].split("\\;").map(_.split("\\-").toList)
  .collect { case key :: value :: _ => key -> value }.toMap
```

It gives me desired result.

I am using

```
data.get("name"),data.get("model"),data.get("number")
```

to access list.
It gives me results in string type. While I want to get result of data.get("number") in integer format.

How do I get result of 'number' in integer format?

Comment: It gives error as toInt is not member of option[String]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data.get("number").map(_.toInt)
```

will return an `Option[Int]`